# Cross Platform Method to Compress and Span Huge Directories

Tags: compression, cross-platform, posix

I have followed several posts on how to create spanned files that can be re-joined later on the same or different system. However, I have never seen a posting on how to do this in a way that works cross platform.

My ask is to support the most popular posix based operating systems (eg. Linux, FreeBSD and Cygwin or WSL on windows). Its not required to support Windows OS itself.

It must be able to handle huge directories of over 100GB, be efficient with minimal intermediate disk usage and with output to be spanned across 256MB files to make [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)ing the files easy to manage. And libraries used must be readily available on various OS's through standard mainstream packages.

The main use-case is to have a script that compresses large VMs for eventual transferring over the wire to a remote backup, on a separate job.

I have tried using the recommended [tar](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar), [split](https://linux.die.net/man/1/split) and [cat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cat) but this does not work in most cases as the implementation across platforms differ in the functionality.

Comment: Could someone with a 300+ reputation create a [spanning] tag? I'm not up to that level yet =)

Comment: `as the implementation […] differ in the functionality` – Therefore you use only options required by POSIX (some old revision maybe, if any platform is legacy), they should be common. Note `tar` is not POSIX, `pax` is. Is there any specific problem with `pax`, `compress`, `split` or `cat`? Compression before `rsync` may not be a good idea because one bit flip in the input may make consecutive parts differ a lot so you cannot benefit from [delta-transfer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265528/108618). Consider transport protocol with compression, target filesystem with compression.

Comment: When I say posit, I am meaning posit based and not meaning pure posix. I'm ok within tar. Question: does sync suffer from bit flips?

Comment: I think `rsync` can deal with little changes fine, but my impression was you're going to compress data *first*. The point is two streams that vary by one bit in the middle, after compression can diverge greatly. If you split and `rsync` the uncompressed data, there will be about one file to resync and `rsync` is smart enough to not send the entire file. If you compress, split and `rsync`, then after the first difference all consecutive files *may* be totally different, `rsync` would need to send them in their entirety, previous versions would be useless.

Comment: I understand your idea and yes, the alteration of intermediate bytes is the key failure mode I've seen. The source system to tar and compress the source directory is on FreeBSD on ZFS and my Hypervisors (on separate hardware) writes the VM clone to a NFS share hosted by FreeBSD. I think that this should be a pretty stable starting point as long as the compression utility also has its own rigorous checksum validation for in memory marshaling of byes. I just read rsync manual about the --partial and --append flags. I'll investigate those options too. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not talking about failure modes. I'm talking about genuine, legitimate small changes. Compression algorithms may encode current data using its resemblance to previously encoded chunks of the input stream. If you change one byte in a stream, everything that follows may get encoded differently because the algorithm is building different dictionary this time. In theory it can be e.g. you change 2MiB and then you need to send 5GiB because after compression files differ so much in comparison to their previous versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is best done using two tools: `tar` and `7zip`. `tar` will package the directory contents alongside all ownership, and metadata and `7zip` will handle the compression and spanning.

This procedure is tested in `FreeBSD` but should be easy to port to Linux or windows via `Cygwin`<sup>*</sup>. This methodology will compress and divide the VMs or other huge directories into smaller chunks making it easier to store and send over the wire for remote backup.

```
# Setup for Bundling
# . `BK_FLDR` is the folder to be backed up and terminal is in parent folder
export BK_FLDR=MY_HUGE_VM_vmbk_20210609
export BK_NAME=${BK_FLDR}_`date '+%m%d%y%H%M%S'`
# . Make a folder to restore to:
mkdir -p ../_bk/${BK_NAME}

# Archive procedure
cd ${BK_FLDR}
tar --use-compress-program "7z a -mx=1 -si ../_bk/${BK_NAME}/${BK_NAME}.t7z -v500m" -cvf *
# . At this point, you will have a bunch of .t7z.nnn files under `./_bk/${BK_NAME}`
# . unless the source dir is less than 500 MB (`-v500m` arg.) there will be only one file

# Restore procedure:
# . Go back to parent dir and create restore folder
cd ..
export OUT_DIR=./_restored/${BK_NAME}
mkdir -p ${OUT_DIR}
# . Restore files
7z x -so ./_bk/${BK_NAME}/${BK_NAME}.t7z.001 | tar -xf - -C ${OUT_DIR}
```

<sup>*</sup> Cygwin may not handle all file data correctly like ownership in windows but should be fine for all file data and timestamps.